# Occupancy per month report

Tags: reporting

I want to report on a hotel room occupancy per month.
I have a room record and a reservation record with arrival and departure dates.
My problem starts when the reservation falls between two months.
How can I design my report to show correct data per month?
Can it be done with report only or must I have some formula?
Can formulas and buckets be used here?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the normalized and reportable way to accomplish this would be to break down the occupancy to be a record-per-day, so that you can easily build a report based on which days have occupancy and group by month.